# Correctly use ajax to make a JSONP request - Error: Cross-Origin Read Blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

**Issue:**

I'm trying to make a JSONP request using ajax, but I'm encountering the below error.

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://nftrade.com/_next/data/_Mat1YwGAWWtzBCNmnbbI/assets/avalanche/0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4/2493.json?chainName=avalanche&contractAddress=0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4&tokenID=2493&callback=jQuery341041842279918868885_1645936498754&_=1645936498755 with MIME type application/json.
```

The below URL works when I access the it using a chrome browser:

> URL:
>
> https://nftrade.com/_next/data/_Mat1YwGAWWtzBCNmnbbI/assets/avalanche/0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4/2493.json?chainName=avalanche&contractAddress=0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4&tokenID=2493

This is the response headers that is returned from the browser:

*Response Headers*

- cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,
  must-revalidate
- cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
- cf-ray: 6e3ec0558e647150-YUL
- content-encoding: gzip
- content-type: application/json
- date: Sun, 27 Feb 2022 04:43:16 GMT
- etag: "10f2-zWjggrplfqo/Q28tqHsMexHhykU"
- expect-ct: max-age=604800,
  report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
- server: cloudflare
- vary: Accept-Encoding

**What I've tried and attempted:**

The below is the code I'm currently using:

```
function getData() {
$.ajax({
    url: `https://nftrade.com/_next/data/_Mat1YwGAWWtzBCNmnbbI/assets/avalanche/0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4/2493.json?chainName=avalanche&contractAddress=0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4&tokenID=2493`,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  })
 }
```

I've also used this ajax code but no luck:

```
function getData() {
var url = "https://nftrade.com/_next/data/_Mat1YwGAWWtzBCNmnbbI/assets/avalanche/0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4/2493.json?chainName=avalanche&contractAddress=0x2cca3a1a45c1b1036d7194cd15a981b8c2f9dee4&tokenID=2493";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
 }};

 xhr.send();
}
```

I used reqbin's code to send an ajax request, which was successful. I'm starting to think it might be an issue with most browsers.

```
https://reqbin.com/req/nfilsyk5/get-request-example
```

Where am I going wrong? Can someone please shed some light? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe for JSONP to work, the response mimetype needs to be `applicaction/javascript` not `application/json` - also, why are you setting a response header (`'access-control-allow-origin':'*'`) in the request? Also, content type makes no sense in a GET request - JSONP isn't a way to circumvent CORS when trying to get JSON - the server MUST recognise a request for JSONP and send the response in the correct JSONP format

Comment: HI there @Bravo. I have already set my contentType to be application/javascript. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: contentType for a get request make no sense - contentType is the type of content you are sending ... a) a GET doesn't send content, b) you aren't sending javascript (or anything) since it's a GET  - understand that the server needs to send JSONP, not JSON, if you expect JSONP ... but the server is sending plain ol' JSON

Comment: solution ... make the request (for JSON, not JSONP) via your server - server code doesn't get blocked by CORS - which is probably what you're trying to bypass by using JSONP, am I correct?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm making the request through my client side code i.e. javascript. I've removed contentType, along with header. But that has not worked for me. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I know you're using client side, because you're using jqueery. Clearly you don't understand what I've said ... you are attempting to request JSONP from some server - that server **does not send JSONP it sends JSON** - the two things are completely different and incompatible

Comment: "I've also used this ajax code but no luck:" - why not? CORS error? that would be because, in browser code, you can't force a site to give you data that it doesn't want to give you - that's what CORS is about - you will need to make the request from **your server** ... i.e. the browser code requests from **your server**, and **your server** makes the request of the other server and returns the data .... commonly called a *proxy request* - i.e. **your server** acts as a *proxy* to get the request from the *other server*

Comment: *I'm starting to think it might be an issue with most browsers* - it's not an issue, it's how the internet works